# Programmatically adding button to UITableViewFooterHeaderView that transitions to another view controller

Tags: swift

[Screenshot of Wikipedia iOS App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWQOa.jpg)

I'm trying to add a button to a header with the button triggering a transition to another view controller like in the above link to a screenshot of Wikipedia's iOS App. I think I'm getting tripped up because I can't (at least I don't think I can?) "present", "show", or "push" another view controller since my class is a UITableViewHeaderFooterView.

I'm new to Swift and hoping I'm not missing something blatantly obvious, but any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
class HeaderCell: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    var editButton: UIButton!

    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        self.editButton = UIButton()
        self.editButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Edit"), for: .normal)

        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.contentView.addSubview(editButton)

        // Plaeholder for constraints
     }

     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
         fatalError()
     }

     @objc func editButtonPressed() {
         // Trigger transition to another view controller
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a few things:
1) use a delegate
2) add target to button from the view controller
3) use responder chain

create a HeaderCellDelegate:

```
protocol HeaderCellDelegate: class {
    func didTapEdit()
}
class HeaderCell: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
   weak var delegate: HeaderCellDelegate?
/* 
existing code 
*/
     @objc func editButtonPressed() {
         // Trigger transition to another view controller
          delegate?.didTapEdit()
     }
}
```

Then in your viewcontroller:

set the HeaderCell delegate to self.

```
headerCell.delegate = self 

extension viewcontroller: HeaderCellDelegate {
   func didTapEdit() {
        //present/push the new view controller
   }
```